# Is this conformal map correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

The question is: does there exist a linear fractional (Möbius) transformation that maps the set $U = \{z \in \Bbb{C} \mid |z-1|<1, |z-i| < 1\}$ onto the quarter plane $\operatorname{Im}z>0, \operatorname{Re}z>0$.

I thought to take the map $z \mapsto \frac{z}{z-1-i}$. The reason I chose this is because I thought to send $0$ to $0$ and send $1+i$ to $\infty$. Because the set $U$ has a right angle at $0$, its image will as well, so intuitively, it seems  like the image will indeed be the first quadrant. However, I can't prove that it maps $U$ onto the first quadrant. Maybe I still need a rotation?

Can someone explain how to do so, or why I am wrong?

Comment: Your intuition seems fine, once you check that the arcs the circles actually map to the axes. You have dealt just with the points $0$ and $1+i$.

Comment: Anyhow, what does the derivative at $0$ of your mapping tell you about your question?

Comment: The derivative is $-1/(i+1)$. Why does that matter?

Comment: That tells you it’s rotating at the origin, doesn’t it?

Comment: Your Möbius transformation $f(z) = \frac{z}{z - (1+i)}$ doesn't work, because $\frac{1}{2}(1+i)\in U$ but $f\left(\frac{1}{2}(1+i)\right) = -1$.

Comment: @RyanTay could you explain where my intuitive argument fails then?